# How to add multiple google cloud datasources using spring

Tags: java, database, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two sql datasources already working locally, but I want to deploy it to two google cloud app-engines (I have it working with one right now). What do I need to change in my application-properties to define a second google instance/database?

I already have links set up in my pom for connections called `sql.instance.second` and `sql.database.second`. I don't know how to define `spring.cloud.gcp.sql...` for a second app-engine. Another option I have is to not run it locally at all but just define a cloud instance when I'm defining the datasources and then define a driver for each, but I'm not too sure how to do that either.

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=@sql.instance.first@
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=@sql.database.first@

primary.datasource.jdbc-url = @mysql.host.first@
primary.datasource.username = @mysql.user.first@
primary.datasource.password = @mysql.pass.first@

secondary.datasource.jdbc-url = @mysql.host.second@
secondary.datasource.username = @mysql.user.second@
secondary.datasource.password = @mysql.pass.second@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by getting rid of this dependency first

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then changing my `application.properties` to this

```
primary.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
primary.datasource.jdbc-url = @mysql.host.first@
primary.datasource.username = @mysql.user.first@
primary.datasource.password = @mysql.pass.first@

secondary.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
secondary.datasource.jdbc-url = @mysql.host.second@
secondary.datasource.username = @mysql.user.second@
secondary.datasource.password = @mysql.pass.second@
```

And deleting

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=@sql.instance.first@
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=@sql.database.first@
```

Change the url of `@mysql.host.first@` in my pom.xml to

```
<mysql.host.first>jdbc:google:mysql:...</mysql.host.first>
```